# sum in list of dictionaries python with exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

how do I get the sum of money and spent from a list of dictionaries where

sum of money = (sum of money of shirt color blue and red) and (sum of money of shirt color yellow and green)

sum of spent = (sum of spent of shirt color blue and red) and (sum of spent of shirt color yellow and green)

should i make new dictionary for shirtcolor blue and red and another one for yellow and green?

```
people = [{'name': 'A', 'shirtcolor':'blue', 'money':'100', spent:'50'}, {'name': 'B', 'shirtcolor':'red', 'money':'70', spent:'50'}, {'name': 'C', 'shirtcolor':'yellow', 'money':'100', spent:'70'}, {'name': 'D', 'shirtcolor':'blue', 'money':'200', spent:'110'},{'name': 'E', 'shirtcolor':'red', 'money':'130', spent:'50'}, {'name': 'F', 'shirtcolor':'yellow', 'money':'200', spent:'70'},{'name': 'G', 'shirtcolor':'green', 'money':'100', spent:'50'}]
```

expected output:

```
Total Money:  500 and 400

Total spent: 260 and 190
```

Answer (score 1):

The data is

```
people = [{'name': 'A', 'shirtcolor': 'blue', 'money': '100', 'spent': '50'},
          {'name': 'B', 'shirtcolor': 'red', 'money': '70', 'spent': '50'},
          {'name': 'C', 'shirtcolor': 'yellow', 'money': '100', 'spent': '70'},
          {'name': 'D', 'shirtcolor': 'blue', 'money': '200', 'spent': '110'},
          {'name': 'E', 'shirtcolor': 'red', 'money': '130', 'spent': '50'},
          {'name': 'F', 'shirtcolor': 'yellow', 'money': '200', 'spent': '70'},
          {'name': 'G', 'shirtcolor': 'green', 'money': '100', 'spent': '50'}]
```

You need only one dictionary where the color is the key and the value is a dictionary with the keys "money" and "spent". Then you can add up all entries there.

```
color_sum = dict()
for entry in people:
    if entry['shirtcolor'] not in color_sum:
        color_sum[entry['shirtcolor']] = {'money':0, 'spent':0}
    color_sum[entry['shirtcolor']]['money'] += int(entry['money'])
    color_sum[entry['shirtcolor']]['spent'] += int(entry['spent'])
```

Using a `defaultdict` does make this easier.

```
from collections import defaultdict

color_sum = defaultdict(lambda: {'money':0, 'spent':0})
for entry in people:
    color_sum[entry['shirtcolor']]['money'] += int(entry['money'])
    color_sum[entry['shirtcolor']]['spent'] += int(entry['spent'])
```

The resulting data in `color_sum` will be this:

```
{'blue': {'money': 300, 'spent': 160}, 
 'red': {'money': 200, 'spent': 100}, 
 'yellow': {'money': 300, 'spent': 140}, 
 'green': {'money': 100, 'spent': 50}}
```

Now you can get the information you need.

```
money_red_blue = color_sum["red"]["money"] + color_sum["blue"]["money"]
money_yellow_green = color_sum["yellow"]["money"]+ color_sum["green"]["money"]
print(f'Total money: {money_red_blue} and {money_yellow_green}')
```

This will output `Total money: 500 and 400`

---

In the comment was the question how to get all the money from shirts that don't have one of the colors green and yellow. In this case we will have to loop over the aggregated data in the dictionary and exclude the items with the keys "green" and "yellow".

```
money = 0
for k, v in color_sum.items():
    if k not in {'green', 'yellow'}:
        money += v['money']
print(money)
```

Or as a one-liner with `sum` and a generator:

```
money = sum(v['money'] for k, v in color_sum.items() if k not in {'green', 'yellow'})
print(money)
```

Comment: thanks! i have another question as im trying to explore more in python, what to do if the red and blue is not specified ( like Total money = (sum of not green or yellow) and (sum of green or yellow))? what would change from u're code above?

Comment: @leafscart I added this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the spent attribute. It should have this syntax: 'spent': 40.
So people will be like this:

people = [{'name': 'A', 'shirtcolor':'blue', 'money':'100', 'spent':'50'}, {'name': 'B', 'shirtcolor':'red', 'money':'70', 'spent':'50'}, {'name': 'C', 'shirtcolor':'yellow', 'money':'100', 'spent':'70'}, {'name': 'D', 'shirtcolor':'blue', 'money':'200', 'spent':'110'},{'name': 'E', 'shirtcolor':'red', 'money':'130', 'spent':'50'}, {'name': 'F', 'shirtcolor':'yellow', 'money':'200', 'spent':'70'},{'name': 'G', 'shirtcolor':'green', 'money':'100', 'spent':'50'}]

Then you need to loop over the list and get all the values.
You can do this by extending this code:

```
money_blue = 0
for i in range(len(people)):
    if people[i]['shirtcolor'] == "blue":
        money += int(people[i]['money'])
    

print(money_blue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```py
product_list=[
    {"name": "A", "shirtcolor":"blue", "money":"100", "spent":"50"},
    {"name": "B", "shirtcolor":"red", "money":"70", "spent":"50"}, 
    {"name": "C", "shirtcolor":"yellow", "money":"100", "spent":"70"},
    {"name": "D", "shirtcolor":"blue", "money":"200", "spent":"110"},
    {"name": "E", "shirtcolor":"red", "money":"130", "spent":"50"},
    {"name": "F", "shirtcolor":"yellow", "money":"200", "spent":"70"},
    {"name": "G", "shirtcolor":"green", "money":"100", "spent":"50"}
]

print(product_list)

#sum of spent for blue and red
blueSpent = sum([int(x["spent"]) for x in product_list if x["shirtcolor"]=="blue" or x["shirtcolor"]=="red"])
print(blueSpent)

#sum of spent for green and yellow
greenSpent = sum([int(x["spent"]) for x in product_list if x["shirtcolor"]=="green" or x["shirtcolor"]=="yellow"])
print(greenSpent)

#sum of spent for blue and red
blueMoney = sum([int(x["money"]) for x in product_list if x["shirtcolor"]=="blue" or x["shirtcolor"]=="red"])
print(blueMoney)

#sum of money for green and yellow
greenMoney = sum([int(x["money"]) for x in product_list if x["shirtcolor"]=="green" or x["shirtcolor"]=="yellow"])
print(greenMoney)
```